# How to obtain the value present from one JS file to another js of viewModels and in main js file?

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js, oracle-jet

[image]

In login.js, a rest API return certain values ,which I have to use in Dashboard.html ,but I am not able get those values in dashboard.js .

I also want to achieve the same in index.html (i.e) I have to get values from login.js.

Now please clarify me below,

How can I pass values from one js to another js file in viewModels?
How can I pass values from viewModel js files to main.js file?

login.js

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojknockout',   'ojs/ojinputtext'], 

function (oj, ko, $,main)
{
 var myviewModel = function()
{
  var self = this;
 self.isLoggedIn = ko.observable(false);
 self.username = ko.observable();
 self.password = ko.observable();
  self.save = function(data, event)
{
    $.ajax({

        url: "my url",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { header parameters },

        success: function(data)
        {   
  var json =JSON.stringify($.parseJSON(data));
 // alert(json);
  var val = JSON.parse(json);

 self.ERROR_CODE= ko.observable(val.Body.processResponse.ERROR_CODE);
 self.ERROR_MSG= ko.observable(val.Body.processResponse.ERROR_MSG);
 if(self.ERROR_CODE()=='S')
 {
     self.isLoggedIn(true);
      window.location="js/views/dashboard.html";
 }
 document.getElementById('errormsg').value=val.Body.processResponse.ERROR_MSG;

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception)
        {
           alert("Not OK!") ;   
        }
   })
}
 }
 return new myviewModel();

});
```

I want to pass self.isLoggedIn value.

Comment: What have you tried? This should work the same way as it does in any object oriented language. You read a property on your instance of login from your main function where you created it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate js file let's say xyzState.js which would be used to hold the data between navigation or js files. 
Now few points to remember here.

1. Don't use observable property in state file instead use plain variable.
2. Inject state file in your login.js file.
3. In your login.vm, assign value to state file variable.
4. Now inject state file in your dashboard.js file.
5. All properties of state should be available in dashboard.vm.

state file would look like this.

```
define('xyzstate',
    ['ko'],
    function (ko) {
        var self = {};

        var clear = function () {          
            self.isLoggedIn= false;

        self = _.extend(self, {
            isLoggedIn: false,           
        });

        return self;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the concept of intermodular communication in Oracle JET or knockout you can say. when we say module it refers to the pair of html and js (view and view-model) files. so when you want to access or communicate from one js to another it means you want to do intermodular communication. 
Knockout provides below function to do so.

ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('homeContent'))

you can also refer to the oracle blog which i found very useful.

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/intermodular_communication_in_oracle_jet1

her ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('homeContent')) you need to get the element id of the module which you want to access the observable variable. let's say there is one module which has chart component and you want to access it's drill handler, you can refer to chart's element id in above code.